# ActiveMQ Artemis federation appears to only attempt round-robin instead of full mesh

Tags: activemq-artemis

I setup a basic federated config using ActiveMQ Artemis. I noticed now that my mesh appears to be performing a round-robin (if I send a message on one broker, the message only gets sent to a single upstream connector and round robins between them).

My connectors look like:

```xml
  <connectors>
    <connector name="kit1-connector1">tcp://192.168.100.15:61618</connector>
    <connector name="kit2-connector1">tcp://192.168.100.16:61618</connector>
  </connectors>
```

My federation config looks like:

```xml
  <federations>
    <federation name="federated-jms">
      <upstream name="kit-1">
        <static-connectors>
          <connector-ref>kit1-connector1</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
        <policy ref="address-federation-policy" />
      </upstream>
      <upstream name="kit-2">
        <static-connectors>
          <connector-ref>kit2-connector1</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
        <policy ref="address-federation-policy" />
      </upstream>

      <policy-set name="address-federation-policy">
        <policy ref="federation-addresses" />
      </policy-set>

      <address-policy name="federation-addresses" max-hops="1">
        <include address-match="jms.topic.federated.#" />
      </address-policy>
    </federation>
  </federations>
```

Any thoughts why federation appears to be round-robin'ing instead of serving to all connectors in my mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to ensure each federated node had a different "federated name". They had to all be globally unique. Soon as that was in place, I showed success in all messages being transferred correctly.

https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/federation-address.html

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as such to help other users who have this same question in the future. It may also help to provide your final configuration to demonstrate exactly what changed to make this work as you wanted.